# Как задать размеры двум картинкам с фиксированными отступами внутри блока неизвестной ширины?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

[image: 2 картинки равной ширины внутри блока неизвестной ширины]

Внешний блок неизвестной ширины. В нём 2 картинки равной ширины и высоты. Нужно сделать так чтоб обе картинки занимали всю полезную площадь по ширине внутри блока, но имели отступ строго 8px между собой и от краёв родительского блока. Поддержка старыми браузерами не нужна.

Comment: Flexbox же легко с этим справится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Заворачиваем картинки в блоки шириной 50%. Картинки растягиваем на 100%. Прописываем `box-sizing: border-box;`, чтобы свойство `width` определяло [ширину самих блоков, а не их содержимого](https://webref.ru/css/box-sizing).
2. Ставим блоки рядышком с помощью `float: left;`. Чтобы родительский блок не схлопнулся, назначаем ему `overflow: hidden;`. В этом случае высота родителя рассчитывается с учётом плавающих в нём потомков.
3. Блокам и контейнеру задаём `padding` в половину от требуемых 8 пикселей. Чтобы не возникал отступ от нижнего края картинок, добавляем им свойство `display: block;`.

Результат: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/0u4caqud/

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 80%;
}

.half {
  float: left;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 50%;
}

.half > img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="half"><img src="//placehold.it/600x300/c69/f9c/?text=Left" alt=""></div>
  <div class="half"><img src="//placehold.it/600x300/69f/9cf/?text=Right" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделал вариант с использованием `display: inline-block`

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.b-unknown-width{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0; /* убираем отступы */
}
.b-unknown__pict-container{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: calc(50% - 12px);
  margin: 0 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.b-unknown__pict-container:first-of-type{
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.b-unknown__pict-container:last-of-type{
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.b-unknown__pict{
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position: relative;  
}
.b-unknown__pict > img{
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-unknown-width">  
  <div class="b-unknown__pict-container">
    <div class="b-unknown__pict">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </div>        
  </div>  
 <div class="b-unknown__pict-container">
    <div class="b-unknown__pict">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </div>        
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1 demo: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/Gqyvzk?editors=110

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.image_wrap{
  display:table;
  margin:auto;
}
.image_wrap p{
  display:table-cell;
  height:120px;
  border:4px double #eee;
}
.image_wrap p img{
  display:table-cell;
  width:200px;
  height:inherit;
  margin:8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_wrap"> 
  <p>
    <img src="http://www.citylaserclinic.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/city-laser-clinics-banner.jpg" alt="" />
 </p>
  <p>
   <img src="http://luxfon.com/pic/201207/2560x1600/luxfon.com-13334.jpg" alt="" />
  </p>
</div>
```